# Jquery Slideshow to have next and previous images shown according to Browser Width

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am looking for a jQuery slideshow to show active image in the center and next previous images in left and right of the active image. the width of active image will be fixed and the other two images will not have fixed widths, it will be calculated according to the browser width.

A [good example of the same](http://goo.gl/KoEe). I have surfed the Google for last 4 days but didn't find any good solution for this.

I found [this plugin](http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancymoves/index.html) similar to this but not up to the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Hero Carousel](http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/)

> Hero Carousel | A jQuery carousel plugin with 100% width & previews of
>   next/previous slide

Comment: thanks for the great plugin....
do the plugin have a user manual or documentation?

Thanks again.

Comment: @user1383873 i cannot find any docs - but if you look at the `.js` file that is part of the download you can see the options / events available

Comment: thanks mate, implemented the hero slider and its working great.
Here is the link http://www.dharamshalatravels.com/